# Cartesian Product for not a finite number of elements has how many elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose P is a set that has m elements and Q is a set with n elements. How many elements will their Cartesian product, PxQ have?

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian product of two sets, $P, Q$ is defined as the set $$P\times Q = \{(p, q)\mid p\in P, \;\;q \in Q\}$$

How many $p$'s are in $P$? Given: $\;m$

How many $q$'s are in $Q$. Given: $\;n$

For each $p \in P$ there are $n$ elements in $Q$, so, for example $$(p_1, q_1), (p_1, q_2), \ldots, (p_1, q_n) \in P\times Q.$$ We get a list of $\bf n$ ordered pairs for each of the $\bf m$ $\; p_i\text{'s }$ in $P$.

So how many ordered pairs are in the set $P\times Q$?

---

To develop some intuition on this, let's start with two very simple, small sets, and use the definition of the Cartesian Product to list all the elements in $P\times Q$

$$P = \underbrace{\{a, b, c\}}_{m = 3},\quad Q = \underbrace{\{1, 2\}}_{n = 2}$$

$$P \times Q = \{(a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 1), (b, 2), (c, 1), (c, 2)\}$$

What is the relationship between the $3$ elements in $P$, the $2$ elements in $Q$, and the $6$ elements in $P \times Q$?

Comment: All the elements of P and Q combine to make the cartesian product. I guess I have a question about what they mean by element. Because if P has m elements and Q has n elements, wouldn't their cross have just m+n unique elements? or is (a,1) counted as a product, in which case, there would be m*n number of products.

Comment: There are indeed $m\times n$ elements in the Cartesian product: the elements are *ordered pairs*: not the *union* of two sets. There are $m \times n$ ordered pairs in $P \times Q$. See the example P, Q in the latter half of my post, and take a look at what elements $P\times Q$ contains.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was confused about, thanks, this helps.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$P\times Q=\{(x,y)|x\in P, y\in Q\}$

If $P=\{x_1,\dots, x_m\}$ and $Q=\{y_1,\dots, y_n\}$ then $P\times Q$ has the following elements:

$(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),\dots ,(x_1,y_n)$ (so $n$ elements)

$(x_2,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\dots ,(x_2,y_n)$ (again $n$ elements)

......

$(x_m,y_1),(x_m,y_2),\dots ,(x_m,y_n)$ (for the $m$-th time $n$ elements)

All these elements mentioned are distinct, so what do you think?

Comment: If you downvote then make clear why. That is also in the interest of the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is a bit confusing to understand, could you elaborate on the third and fourth line?

Comment: Do you understand that $(x_i,y_j)$ is an element of $P\times Q$ if and only if $x_i$ is an element of $P$ and $y_j$ is an element of $Q$? In the third and fourth line I am just *mentioning* elements of $P\times Q$ one by one.

Comment: Reading your conversation with amWhy I understand that you had to overcome some confusion. Next to the (Cartesian) product there is also a socalled *coproduct* of $P$ and $Q$. It is the disjoint union of $P$ and $Q$ and has $m+n$ elements. That is something else.